# Calculating Time Complexity of Algorithm Using Incrementor Variable

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, counting

I am trying to calculate the time complexity of an algorithm using `n` in the code below.

I have a working solution to a coding challenge to sort a stack using only another stack, and I've added a counter variable `n` that is incremented anywhere an element in the stack is pushed, popped, or held.

The following code is written in JavaScript:

```
const sortStack = (stack) => {
  let n = 0;
  sorted = new Stack();
  while (stack.storage.length) {
    tmp = stack.pop();
    n += 1;  
    if (tmp >= sorted.peek()) {
      sorted.push(tmp);
      n += 1;
    } else {
      while (tmp < sorted.peek()) {
        stack.push(sorted.pop());
        n += 1;
      }
      sorted.push(tmp);
      n += 1;
    }
  }
  console.log("n: ", n);
  return sorted;
}

sortedStack = sortStack(s);
sortedStack.printContents();
```

If my calculations and usage of `n` are correct, then this algorithm has an input `n` of 6 (length of `stack`) with a final `n` of 30, which would give it a time complexity of O(N*5).

Is this correct?

Comment: @dkaeae I'd really just like to know if my above calculations are correct--I tried on Code Review and it was suggested that I post on Computer Science.

Comment: We usually discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/).

Comment: @dkaeae The original answer is a bit over my head even though I just accepted it--if telling me whether my above logic is correct or not--even just this once in a tiny little comment--is outside the realm of possibility, then can you at least tell me where I could get an answer to this specific question?

Comment: check how counter depends on n value